# powershell - multiply each value in array

Tags: arrays, powershell, multiplication

how can i multiply each value by 10 in an array?
the given array is

```
[int]$arr = 0..1000
```

now the way i have tried to solve it is:

```
foreach($valuex10 in $arr)
{
      $valuex10 = $valuex10 * 10
}
```

I think that should work, but it does not, i get the error "cant convert to System.Int32" if i try to give every variable the [int] (tag?) the ISE tells me it cant process it because there is no variable to start with.
So what is wrong?

creating a new array is not allowed.

Comment: Remove `[int]` or use the correct `[int[]]` and use the index notation $arr[$i] = $arr[$i] * 10 inside a normal `for` loop on $i.

Comment: gonna try that after a smokebreak, could you tell me where i can read up on those notations?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this:

```
$arr = 0..1000
for($i = 0; $i -lt $arr.Length; $i++){
    $arr[$i] = $arr[$i] * 10
}
```

Comment: hey k7s5a --> our teacher disallowed using a new array, shouldve mentioned that in the Post

Comment: Add this fact to your question and try to understand what the code does!

Comment: $arr = 0..1000  (thats the array, got that)
for($i = 0; $i -lt $arr.Length; $i++)  (thats the for loop, with the runtimevariable (?) being 0, the condition being if runtimevariable less than $arr.length (but why array.length?), and the action of incrementing +1   {
    $arr[$i] = $arr[$i] * 10 (thats the codeblock, which defines $arr (and every element in it as element * 10?)
}

Comment: ($i -lt $arr.Length) -> That´s the loop condition.
$arr.Length -> Is the length of the array. In your case 1000 cause you added 1000 items.
$i = 0 -> Is the current loop index. $i++ -> increment the index after each round.
$arr[$i] -> is the item of the current round index. Try this: $arr[0] and this $arr[$arr.Length-1]

Comment: Sorry, I think i got my wires crossed.    You mean to tell me that its not possible doing a for loop on a Null-Array?

Answer (score 1):

A functional approach, where the array is piped into the `ForEach-Object` command (alias `%`) which invokes a [*script block*](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_script_blocks) (the expression that follows the command name, starting with `{` and ending after matching `}`) for each element in the array. The result of script block invocation on each element as done by the command, makes up a new array:

```
0..1000 | % { $_ * 10 }
```

The above is an expression -- it can be assigned to a variable. Evaluating it yields an array where first element is 10 times larger than the first element of the `1..1000` array, second is 10 times larger than the second element of the `1..1000` array, and so on.

By the way, script blocks are "first class" objects in Powershell, you can assign them and use them like any other.

You can for instance reuse a script block:

```
$MultiplyByTen = { $_ * 10 }
1..1000 | % $MultiplyByTen
```